# Why is 'Go To Definition' giving me multiple options?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019. When I right-click a function call and select 'Go To Definition', I get two options, apparently because the code-base has two global functions with the same name and signature.

Why is this able to compile? Since it does compile, it must be unambiguous which one is being linked, and therefore it should be possible to go to the definition without having to make a selection, right?

Comment: ***it must be unambiguous which one is being linked*** I don't think it is. I believe the code violates the one definition rule if the definitions are different but have the same signature.

Comment: the name is not enough to specify who is who, if the signature are different (out of the return type) the function are different too. For instance `void f(int) {...}`and `void f(int, float){...}` and `int f(float){...}` are 3 different functions

Comment: @bruno the signatures are not different; I have two global functions with the same arguments and return-type.

Comment: @drescherjm, just to clarify, you're saying the compiler is internally making a decision but not throwing an error? Is it possible that this is resolved through header inclusion, but Intellisense/'go to definition' just does a simple string-search through my entire project?

Comment: This is the job of the linker not the compiler. I believe if the definitions are different this is Undefined behavior.

Comment: The parser in the indexer might not be smart enough to figure out which is the real deal.

Comment: @afarley are these functions `static` or at least one of them ?

Comment: Violating the one definition rule is means the code is ill formed - no diagnostic required.  You get whatever you get as far as the C++ standard cares.

Comment: Related: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)

Comment: @bruno Nope, they are not static.

Comment: I recalled if click on a function of interface, vs will show you ever function with the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from @NathanOliver and @drescherjm, it sounds like this is undefined behavior resulting from a violation of the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: And note that neither the compiler nor the linker are required to detect ODR violations, and nor are they required to show any diagnostic. It's your mistake, and you have to fix it.

Comment: @Useless I mean, technically, it's not my mistake. But I still have to fix it.